# Hybrid bike how much should I inflate tyres

Tags: tire, hybrid-bike

Hi I just bought a hybrid bike btwin riverside 3. It has 28 inch tires and weights 15kgs. My weight is 75kg. How much should I inflate my tires. And how often should I refill?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For the correct tyre pressure, you should have a look on the wall of your tyre.

Obviously different tyre manufacturers will mould their tyres differently, but here is an example (one of my tyres, I have raided the flour cupboard to make the marking stand out!):

[image]

So we have: **Max. LuftDruck / Inflation: 4.5 Bar / 65 PSI**

These tyres are Continental, a German manufacturer, and the word LuftDruck means (surprisingly) air pressure.

Note that this tyre is on my offroad bike (26") so will probably show different values to those on your hybrid (I'd expect 75psi or thereabouts, but you should check).

For the frequency you should check the pressure: some people will say every ride, I generally go for every week or two for the bikes I ride regularly, every ride for those I don't.

Comment: How often to check pressure depends on the volume (mainly width) of the tire, the target pressure, and tube quality.  Larger (fatter) tires require less frequent checks, both because they contain more air to begin with and because they run at a lower pressure.  And some "lightweight" tubes (including some very expensive ones) "leak down" very fast.  I usually air up my 700c 35 tires running 100 psi every other day.  Narrower tire will need checking daily, fat tires can get away with once a week or so.  (Be sure to get a "floor pump" with built-in pressure gauge for checking/filling the tires.)

Comment: And note that the sidewall pressure is the "max" -- you can run lower (or even about 10% higher), but generally (except for offroad or other special situations) you should run at the max or maybe 10% lower.