# Recommended Tire pressure

Tags: mountain-bike, tire-pressure

Looking for recommend. Tire pressure for a 26in MTN bike. Im around 185lbs.

I am fixing my bike up, and I want to make sure not to over inflate as I do not want to blow a tire.

Comment: There are many duplicate questions on this SE -- use the search feature to find them. In short, you're going to have to experiment (depending on tire size, riding conditions, personal preference, etc). The pressure you should run will be significantly lower than whats written on the tire sidewall, typically, though.

Comment: ...and [this question](http://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/16482/hybrid-bike-how-much-should-i-inflate-tyres/16483#16483) includes a photo showing what you should be looking for on the sidewall